# Аналогии между ооп и базами данных

Tags: ооп, база-данных

Расскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли связь между иерархией классов в ООП и связями сущностей в БД. В частности интересует такой момент. Пусть имеется ряд сущностей у которых  скажем пять полей идентичны. в ооп их можно вынести в родительский класс, а данные классы от него унаследовать. а вот как в базах? можно ли создать некую родительскую сущность с этими полями? Скажем, есть ли в базах понятие абстрактной сущности, то есть таблицы, для которой нельзя создать объект. Надеюсь, понятно выразился)

Comment: Связь есть -- буквы те же. А то, что Вы описываете, сильно напоминает нормализацию

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> В самом простом случае наследования от
> одного класса- есть 3 варианта.
>
> 1. Создать таблицу для суперкласса с его атрибутами, и каждому сабклассу.
>    по таблице с их атрибутами. Связаны
>    через примари ключ.
> 2. Создать одну таблицу для суперкласса со всеми атрибутами,
>    включая сабклассы.
> 3. Создать таблицы только для сабклассов, каждая будет включать
>    атрибуты сабкласса + суперкласса.

[отсюда](http://forum.vingrad.ru/forum/s/45f149154356f5ce4f744e46955ed769/topic-47560.html)